# How to fit modal video.js player responsively into viewport?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, video.js

I want to add a modal [video.js](/questions/tagged/video.js) player, that:

- has the same aspect ratio as the video (videos have different aspect ratios)
- is centered in the viewport
- if the size (width, height, both) of the video is smaller than the viewport

  - has the size of the video
- if the size (width, height, both) of the video is larger than the viewport

  - scales down to the maximum size that fits the viewport

I tried styling the video player itself as well as styling an enclosing `div`. I tried `video.js`'s built in `vjs-fluid` and `vjs-fill`. And many combinations of the above - to no avail.

What could a solution to this problem look like?

Here is a bare minimum code template (also in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfntz76v/)):

```css
.video-js {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How to fit modal video.js player responsively into viewport?</title>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <h1>
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit
      in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </article>
  <video id="my-player" class="video-js vjs-fluid" controls preload="auto" poster="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </source>
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
    </source>
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </source>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
        supports HTML5 video
      </a>
    </p>
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no way to know unless we see your code :) Make a working JSFiddle so everyone can have a look

Comment: I tried many many ways, that did all not succeed. I added a bare minimum setup. SO did not accept the `video.js` libraries, but I added a [link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfntz76v/).

Comment: Were you able to solve this?
Stuck in a similar problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I remember, I settled with some other solution at the time. Please let me know, if you find an answer.